# MySql in Rails 3 fast with User.first and slow with User.first(1) - why?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have a table with about 500,000 users in it. When I use my Rails 3.0 console and type

```
User.first
```

I get the result immediately.  But when I type

```
User.first(1)
```

it takes several seconds. What could be causing this?

Note: the same thing happens between

```
User.last
```

and

```
User.last(1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I turned on log displaying in Erb (Rails 3.0.7) and yield following

```
1.8.7 :004 > User.first
  User Load (4.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 1, email: "user@project.ru">
1.8.7 :005 > User.first(1)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
 => #<User id: 1, email: "user@project.ru">
1.8.7 :008 > User.first(2)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
 => [#<User id: 1, email: "user@project.ru", #<User id: 2, email: "user@gmail.com">]
```

So we can see that when you call `first` without arguments it works as expected, but when we call `first` with a `number` as argument it loads all users for DB and then leave only `number` elements in users array.

In [recent Rails code](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-first) of `first` looks like this

```
def first(*args)
  if args.any?
    if args.first.kind_of?(Integer) || (loaded? && !args.first.kind_of?(Hash))
      limit(*args).to_a
    else
      apply_finder_options(args.first).first
    end
  else
    find_first
  end
end
```

So it is quite ok. But in [older version like Rails 3.0.7](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/827e5de60f27c6b559640eda7b79857050a72d9e/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L114) it is:

```
def first(*args)
  if args.any?
    if args.first.kind_of?(Integer) || (loaded? && !args.first.kind_of?(Hash))
      to_a.first(*args)
    else
      apply_finder_options(args.first).first
    end
  else
    find_first
  end
end
```

So as you can see if `first` argument is `Integer` ActiveRecord load all data, convert it into array and call Array's `first` method, which has following behaviour: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-first

Comment: Fascinating! So it seems like this was a bug in 3.0.7?